# MySQL Right Join Data Not Counting Correctly

Tags: mysql, count, right-join

I have this data:

```
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
| employee_id | assignment_started | assignment_terminated |
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|           1 | 2018-07-01         | (NULL)                |
|           2 | 2018-09-01         | (NULL)                |
|           3 | 2018-10-13         | (NULL)                |
|           4 | 2018-10-13         | (NULL)                |
|           5 | 2018-10-15         | 2019-07-17            |
|           6 | 2018-11-01         | (NULL)                |
|           7 | 2019-01-14         | (NULL)                |
|           8 | 2019-01-24         | (NULL)                |
|           9 | 2019-07-01         | 2019-07-30            |
+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

I want to count employees by month that are under assignment. To determine if the employee is under assignment, I need to check if the date I am looking for is between assigment_started and assignment terminated. But if assignmen_termiated is null I set it on NOW().

Also, I have a date range I need to check. So if I have a date range from 2018-01-01 until 2019-07-30 I need to count employees by every month and if there are no employees under assignment on some months I should have 0 value as count.

To create DATE RANGE MONTHS I use this code:

```sql
select DISTINCT CONCAT(YEAR(gen_date),' ',MONTHNAME(gen_date)) AS month_name FROM 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) gen_date FROM 
(select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0, 
(select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1, 
(select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2, 
(select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3, 
(select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v 
WHERE gen_date between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and '2019-08-31 23:59:59'
```

What I get from this is:

```
+-------------+
| month_name  | 
+-------------+
|2018 January |
|2018 February| 
|2018 March   | 
|2018 April   | 
|         ... | 
|         ... |
|         ... |
|2019 August  | 
+-------------+
```

From the data above you will see that until 2018 July I would have employee count 0, and for 2018 July I would have 1 employee, for example on 2018 September I should have count 5 because there are 5 employees that were working on that month.

To shorten the question, I use this code to achieve what I need, but for some reason count results are incorrect... I am trying to figure this out, but no idea why am I getting this results that you can find in fiddle below.

```sql
SELECT calendar.month_name, COUNT(employee_id) AS emp_count
FROM job_order_employees
RIGHT JOIN (select DISTINCT CONCAT(YEAR(gen_date),' ',MONTHNAME(gen_date)) AS month_name FROM 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) gen_date FROM 
(select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0, 
(select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1, 
(select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2, 
(select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3, 
(select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v 
WHERE gen_date between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and '2019-08-31 23:59:59') as calendar
ON STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(calendar.month_name,'01'),'%Y %M %d') BETWEEN job_order_employees.assignment_started AND IFNULL(job_order_employees.assignment_terminated,NOW())
GROUP BY calendar.month_name
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(calendar.month_name,'%Y %M')
```

Here is some sample data:

```
-- Dumping structure for table d-works-test.job_order_employees
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `job_order_employees` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `assignment_started` date NOT NULL,
  `assignment_terminated` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Dumping data for table d-works-test.job_order_employees: ~14 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `job_order_employees` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `job_order_employees` 
(`id`
, `employee_id`
,`assignment_started`
, `assignment_terminated`) VALUES
(1, 1,'2019-05-29', NULL),
(2, 2,'2018-09-19', NULL),
(3, 3,'2018-07-01', NULL),
(4, 4, '2018-10-13', NULL),
(5, 5, '2018-10-13', NULL),
(6, 6, '2019-02-01', NULL),
(7, 7, '2019-01-14', NULL),
(8, 8, '2018-11-01', NULL),
(9, 8, '2019-01-01', NULL),
(10, 9, '2019-02-01', NULL),
(11, 9, '2019-01-24', NULL),
(12, 9, '2018-12-31', NULL),
(13, 10, '2018-10-13', '2019-07-17'),
(14, 10, '2019-07-01', '2019-07-17');
```

And DB Fiddle of same: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8dUFx1DWiyypbkx9s2cYyG/1

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: My initial thoughts are that your date handling seems a little suspect; the order of fiddle's results seems to be rather random.

Comment: Ah, I see, your logic is a little incorrect. That BETWEEN is collecting assignments active on the first of each month. You need to check for overlap of the start and end of the month with the start and end of the assignment.

Comment: @Uueerdo For some reason fiddle's results are not sorted, but in my IDE results are, but the values are the same as I am getting...

Comment: Learn what LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right/left [sic] table column to be not NULL after a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. (This is a faq for LEFT JOIN.)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: "For some reason fiddle's results are not sorted" The reason is that tables have no order & query result sets with ORDER BY have (partial) order. This is a basic of SQL, learn about it. (You have never been told to expect order without ORDER BY, so why do you?) Also, please clarify via edits, not comments. But--what is the point of that comment?

Comment: @philipxy keep in mind that MySQL is not my strongest side and also not my everyday job to manage some complex queries or to solve some data problem on the database side. But I will keep in mind your guidelines for further problems solving. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably simplify your logic quite a bit by holding off formatting the month strings until the final step; you're doing a lot of work back converting for something only relevant to the final formatting.

This will also help because then you can define the inclusive start and exclusive end of each month, like so:

SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) gen_date 
FROM (stuff) v

Then, use that like so:

```
SELECT [format rangestart here], COUNT(employee_id) AS emp_count
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT gen_date AS rangestart, gen_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS rangeend 
   FROM v
   WHERE gen_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND'2019-08-31 23:59:59'
) as calendar
LEFT JOIN job_order_employees AS joe
   ON IFNULL(joe.assignment_terminated,NOW()) >= calendar.rangestart
   AND joe.assignment_started <= calendar.rangeend
GROUP BY calendar.rangestart
ORDER BY calendar.rangestart 
;
```

The join logic (overlap checking condition) looks a bit weird until you realize where it comes from. It's the simplification of "not ones that don't overlap".

`NOT (ended < range_start || started > range_end)`
simplifies to
`ended >= range_start && started <= range_end`

---

**Edit:** The above wrongly assumed the subquery was generating every month; the following should work

**calendar query** *(this will cover about 83 years, you can add another t# table with a multiplier of 1000 to get 833 years worth)*:

```
SELECT '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL t0 + t1 * 10 + t2 * 100 MONTH AS start_date
    , '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 + t0 + t1 * 10 + t2 * 100 MONTH AS end_date  
FROM (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0
    , (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1
    , (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2
```

**Final query**:

```
SELECT [format calendar.start_date here]
   , COUNT(employee_id) AS emp_count
FROM ( 
   *calendar query above goes here* 
) as calendar
LEFT JOIN job_order_employees AS joe
   ON IFNULL(joe.assignment_terminated,NOW()) >= calendar.start_date
   AND joe.assignment_started < calendar.end_date
WHERE calendar.start_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-08-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY calendar.start_date
ORDER BY calendar.start_date
;
```

Note: I also changed the operators on the overlap comparison; since the generated end_date is non-inclusive, it should have been
`NOT (ended < range_start || started >= range_end)`
which simplifies to `ended >= range_start && started < range_end`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You are right about the complexity of the query and a lot of formating. I modified the query and I managed to simplify it, but can you please use the fiddle and your solution on the data I provided. I am still struggling to get the data right, maybe I missed something from your solution...

Comment: Oh, I see, I assumed your `v` subquery was getting the first of each month, not every day, then using the distinct and format to reduce it down. Taking a look now.

Comment: you solved my problem. Thank you for your time, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using coalesce to enter the current date. Then I would create the list of months that need counting and join that on the list of assignments grouped by employee and month.